# Create a pop up page when loading a page in Zen Cart

Tags: php, zen-cart

I have a Zen Cart project and I want to show an AJAX pop up box (on body load).

Pop up must be shown only on the home page.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In the **tpl_main_page.php** file, on body load use this condition:

```
<?php
if ($_REQUEST['main_page']=='index' || $_REQUEST['main_page']=='')
{
?>
<body onload="Popupajax()">
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<body>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: <?php
if ($_REQUEST['main_page']=='index' || $_REQUEST['main_page']=='')
{
?>
<body onload="Popupajax()">
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<body>
<?php
}
?>